# R: do we have a devtools version of ?base::getNamespace

Tags: r, namespaces, devtools

For an installed R package, we have

```
base::getNamespace('stats')
base::getNamespace('MASS')
```

For a development version of our own package (that you load via `devtools::load_all(".")`), do we have a function of similar purpose?  We know this won't work

```
base::getNamespace('.') # Error: there is no package called ‘.’
```

Edit: Thanks to everyone in the comments! Here's a summary of the discussion

```
getNamespace(normalizePath('.')) # error
getNamespace(pkgload::pkg_name('.')) # works!
getNamespace(basename(normalizePath('.'))) # works, if directory name is the same as package name
```

Comment: I think you might be confusing two concepts. In `load_all(".")` the dot it not an R symbol but the standard placeholder for the current directory in which you develop.  The package name is then given by `DESCRIPTION`.  Where is in `getNamespace()` the argument is a package name.  Or maybe I misunderstood your question.

Comment: You should just be able to use `base::getNamespace("your-package-name-here")` after you've run `load_all`. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Are you looking for `getNamespace(pkgload::pkg_name())` ? If you use {devtools} you'll have {pkgload} installed as well and `pkgload::pkg_name()` will fetch the name of the package from the description (`read.dcf("DESCRIPTION")[, "Package"]` would work too)

Comment: Thanks to you all!  I have put the solution in the original post.